# join to sql queries as one to get the total percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have those two queries below,

Busy

```
SELECT epoch as time_sec, 
       count(1) as Used 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  server in ($server) 
       and bw > 0 
       and interface in ($interface)
```

Not Busy

```
SELECT epoch as time_sec, 
       count(1) as NotUsed 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  server in ($server) 
       and bw = '0' 
       and interface in ($interface)
```

I'm trying to get the percentage of how much was busy.

I figured out how to do the two SQL queries to get the total, but I don't know how to join them to get a total percentage of server being used.

Anyone can help?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG( b2 > 0) as busy_ratio
FROM tablename
WHERE server in ($server) and 
      interface in ($interface);
```